# Running .sh file with one button click

Tags: command-line, scripts, vpn, sh

I am a linux beginner and I am trying to automate a small task on my computer.
In order to connect to my vpn, I have to open my terminal and type `nordvpn connect`

I have created a simple .sh script that does this for me.

```
#!/bin/bash
nordvpn connect
```

The problem is that to run this file I have to open my terminal and write `./vpn.sh

 Is there a way I can automate this to be done with a single click?

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu desktop, but if there is a way to map keyboard shortcuts to commands, that might work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure its possible. I've found several similar questions on this forum but most are from 10 years ago

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about a click, but you could add a keyboard shortcut: Open Settings/Keyboard shortcuts, scroll to the bottom and press the plus sign. Give a name to your shortcut, enter `/path/to/nordvpn connect` as the command and then select a keyboard shortcut. Note: `/path/to/nordvpn` should be replaced by the output of `which nordvpn`.

Comment: Hey that works great! Thank you. Is there any way to keep the terminal open or to have some other visual que that my vpn is running?

Comment: I would post that as a separate question, but if you are on Ubuntu 20.04/default win mgr, you could start with wg-indicator (https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2027/wg-indicator/) and modify ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/wg-indicator@asterios.member.fsf.org/extension.js to look for whatever thing is active when nordvpn is active. I use the integrity.st vpn, and I use ["/bin/bash", "-c", "ip a | grep SEintegrity_vpn"] to check whether the vpn is active or not.

Answer (score 2):

To complement the very good alternative suggestion of Niclas Börlin to [set up a shortcut](https://askubuntu.com/a/1353058/558158) key for this, I can add how the script can be set up to be run with a single mouse click, as originally asked.

You can [create](https://askubuntu.com/a/1289510/558158) a `.desktop` launcher for the command. Such launcher will appear in your Application menu, from where you can pin it to the dock, providing one-click access.