# Remove the "Lock Screen" shortcut from the gnome menu on 22.04

Tags: gnome, .desktop, appmenu

I'm trying to remove the shortcut to "Lock Screen" from the start menu, but I can't seem to find the .desktop file that would be associated with it. Whenever I go to take a screenshot, I type in screen and then enter, with 22.04 there's a new entry on the start menu for lock screen which is apparently a closer match to screen than screenshot. To compensate for this design failure, I would like to remove the shortcut, where would it be located?

[image: menu list]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove Lock Option from Top Panel](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1412990/remove-lock-option-from-top-panel)

Comment: That's how to disable the lock screen, which is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking to remove a link from the app menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not from a desktop file, it is hardcoded.

The workaround for this would be to tweak the gnome-shell's core files which is by creating the gnome-shell extension to tweak it.

the workaround seems a little overkill but it works.

Here is the Github link for extension files https://github.com/PRATAP-KUMAR/hide-lock-screen-item-from-show-apps-menu

[image]

create the folder in your local directory

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/hideLockScreenItem@user.extension.mail
```

put the two downloaded files (`extension.js` and `metadata.json`) in the above directory.

refresh the gnome-shell if you are using `X` or logout and login if `Wayland`.

to enable the extension, run the below command

```
gnome-extensions enable hideLockScreenItem@user.extension.mail
```

it may once again be needed to refresh or re-login as in the above step.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow thank you so much for the help and especially for writing a gnome extension just to answer this question.

Comment: Yep, that works