# What does the system tray "Lock" button actually do [22.10]?

Tags: lock-screen, system-tray, 22.10

Ok yes, it sound like a dumb question as I am indeed talking about this:

[image]

But my question is a little more complicated and has identical origins as the question asked here: [Remove lock button/icon from system tray Ubuntu 18.04 with gnome 3.28](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410411/remove-lock-button-icon-from-system-tray-ubuntu-18-04-with-gnome-3-28)

However, I don't necessarily want to disable the lock button, I just need to edit its behavior somehow - as it appears to alter the X-session. So, is there some command binding for this button or configuration file I can view/change to see where the locking behavior comes from?

Answer (score 1):

The system tray "lock" button locks your screen. It keeps your current session alive, but kicks a password protected screensaver in action. You can return to your session providing the password.

The idea of this function is to allow you to briefly walk away from your computer preventing others to access your desktop in the mean time. In a default Ubuntu install, the shortcut key <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> performs the same function of that button.

To edit its behavior, you will need some developer skills. You will need to edit some source code, and perhaps you will need to recompile some components of Gnome Shell.

Comment: Can you point me to where this source is located? I was able to discover that it likely depends on the display manager e.g. it seems that the GUI calls the equivalent of `dm-tool lock` (if using lightdm). After learning that lightdm uses light-locker under the hood (which just changes the Virtual Terminal and throws up the greeter) - I'm looking to see if there are other alternatives that don't do this but allow for identical lock and login screen.

Comment: No, sorry, my knowledge does not extent into the source code.