# Lock icon system tray (ubuntu 23.10)

Tags: icons, system-tray

I'm running Ubuntu 23.10.

Does anyone know what this lock with an exclamation in my system tray means in the picture below? I don't see it described in the [official docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/status-icons.html).

I have a VPN setup, but it's not currently connected and there's a separate icon that shows when connecting (and connected). My wifi works fine. And, when I plug in ethernet it shows a separate icon for that.

My drive (nvme) has hardware encryption enabled with sedutil, but I don't think that's related to this icon (it's not installed in the main partition...it's in the pre-boot partition).

I temporarily disabled all extensions just to see if it was from one, but it still remains.

Nothing is broken, but I'm just curious. :-P

[image: System Tray Icons]

**NOTE:** This is different from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410411/remove-lock-button-icon-from-system-tray-ubuntu-18-04-with-gnome-3-28) which refers to the lock screen icon on the pop-down menu from the system tray.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove lock button/icon from system tray Ubuntu 18.04 with gnome 3.28](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1410411/remove-lock-button-icon-from-system-tray-ubuntu-18-04-with-gnome-3-28)

Comment: No, that question is about the lock button on the pop-down menu when you click on the system tray. Different icon. They put a link to their picture in the question.